# How to insert a line in rc.local file using sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have to insert a line `sh /root/startgateway.sh &` in a file /etc/rc.local
I have used sed command to do it:
`sed -i "/^exit0/i\sh /root/startgateway.sh &" /etc/rc.local`

But after executing this sed command more then once it keeps adding new `sh /root/startgateway.sh &`
What could be the way to not make a duplicate each time executing it instead it replaces it.

Comment: Don't just blindly use the `-i` flag if you're not sure what is the outcome/output and please make a backup of anything that you're editing.

Comment: I expect `exit0` is an error anyway, so you probably want to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

If the `exit 0` line is (as usual) the last line in the file, you could replace it with your line rather than insert that.